# Gravatar change?

Tags: support, gravatar

My gravatar has been 
[image] since I joined in 2009

and has now changed (where not cached) to

[image]

Why? I have not changed anything and it changed whilst I was just browsing

the other questions are not answering this case.
The gravatar was the same in small and large mode so not gravatar issue.

It seems to be all sites not just Area 51

Comment: @egreg the issue is very strongly user-dependent, so you should find other users (possibly in chat) who still see your old gravatar. Although you have a manually set avatar now which is different from the auto-generated red one I see on chat.MSE for you, so I assume you've solved it by now.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I manually set the old one, the red one I got was awful